# How to declare array inside array in yaml file

Tags: snakeyaml

for example : rate:

```
{floor: '1', functionId: BDEB1, 
baseRates: { baseRateAgreementLevel: baseRateAgreementLevel,name: LIBOR GBP 1 Month, value: 0.1}
}
```

Above rate is a array and baserate is another array which is inside rate array

Getting error "Cannot create property" while declaring array inside array in snake yaml file.

Comment: Indentation is relevant here, so I can't edit that for you.  Put 4 spaces to the left of each line to indicate a line of code in markup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you meant to write:

```
rate:
    floor: '1'
    functionId: BDEB1
    baseRates: 
        baseRateAgreementLevel: baseRateAgreementLevel
        name: LIBOR GBP 1 Month
        value: 0.1
```

Is this what you wanted?  Take a look [here](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=%20%20%20%20rate%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20floor%3A%20%271%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20functionId%3A%20BDEB1%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20baseRates%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20baseRateAgreementLevel%3A%20baseRateAgreementLevel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20LIBOR%20GBP%201%20Month%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%200.1&type=json) for a json equivalent representation.

Comment: Could you add the generated json representation in your answer aswell because that link might die some time